# Best practice for detecting and formatting for mobile browsers

Tags: mobile, web, jquery-mobile

I host a small web shop for a client who wants it to be easily accessible from mobile devices.

How do I detect if the user is browsing my site from a mobile device?

When I have done that, should I:

1. Check if the user has mobile device and then forward them to another site?
   I think the advantages would be:

   - I can optimize layout from both sites for screensize
   - I can use different techniques in the two sites (eg. jquery mobile for mobile)
2. Use CSS for the different screen sizes => like on [tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/responsive-web-design-a-visual-guide/)
   I think the advantage would be:

   - I only need one site but it seems to me heaps of work when talking about a small webshop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting a mobile browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you should try using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/) page structure with your own CSS and JavaScript for non-mobile devices.

You can easily [detect user's browser](http://detectmobilebrowser.com/) and conditional script includes as per html5 [boilerplate]:[3](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

```
/* Grade-A Mobile Browsers (Opera Mobile, Mobile Safari, Android Chrome)
consider this: www.cloudfour.com/css-media-query-for-mobile-is-fools-gold/ */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
```

Main things to consider when aiming at iPhone users:

- ensure there's no vital flash objects
  on the page as it isn't supported by
  many mobile browsers (yet?)
- appropriate screen size (using
  viewport meta tag)
- keeping in mind that there's no mouse
  cursors, meaning no
  hover/double-clicks are available any
  mouse dragging gestures are different
  on touch devices
- remember all pop-ups are open in new
  tabs and won't be seen at the same
  time as the main window, use
  javascript modal divs as alternative
- test all your javascript and css to
  ensure everything looks and works the
  same (Safari requires -webkit- prefix
  for the newest CSS properties)
- create a Home screen icon for your
  website (a nice thing to have)

most of these things are covered [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/_index.html)

take a look at [Safari Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action) for tutorials/videos/coding how to's etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options but this is my favorite:

- http://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/

Comes with a API in a couple of different languages as well

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery at all if you don't want to use it. We don't. Not that there's anything wrong with that.

Number 2 is the best option. If you create a site with mobile in mind first, it's far, far easier to expand and manipulate for the desktop than trying to shrink things to a mobile screen.

Comment: jQuery (mobile) is just an example. It seems to me that there are is a different user experience when surfing mobile.So you would start from a site for mobile devices and if the user has a screen width that is bigger then eg 480px change the formatting

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Mobile is currently in beta 1 right now.  Beta 2 will be out within a month.  It is fairly stable at the moment and you can gain a lot of knowledge about what is considered "best practice" from them.  You can use media queries for screen sizes for different platforms which JQuery Mobile also supports.

http://jquerymobile.com/